# Jasmine - correctly mocking an object with a constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I'm trying to mock the native WebSocket in a jasmine test for Angular, I can spy on the constructor and `send` function, but I can't figure out how to spoof a call of `onmessage`.

WebSocket is extracted to an Angular constant: `webSocket`.

My test looks like this:

```
describe('Data Service', function () {

  var dataService,
    $interval,
    ws;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('core', function ($provide) {
      ws = jasmine.createSpy('constructor');
      ws.receiveMessage = function (message) {
        this.onmessage(message);
      };
      $provide.constant('webSocket', ws);
    });

    inject(function (_dataService_, _$interval_) {
      dataService = _dataService_;
      $interval = _$interval_;
    });
  });

  it("should call subscribers when a message is received", function () {
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy('onMessage callback');

    function message(type) {
      return {
        data: {
          type: type,
          data: 'data'
        }
      };
    }

    // Subscribe to messages via the exposed function.
    // Subscribe to one of them twice to test that all subscribers are called and not just the first one.
    dataService.onMessage(21, callback);
    dataService.onMessage(21, callback);
    dataService.onMessage(22, callback);
    dataService.onMessage(23, callback);

    // Pick 3 numbers that are valid data types to test.
    ws.receiveMessage(message(21));
    ws.receiveMessage(message(22));
    ws.receiveMessage(message(23));

    expect(callback.calls.count()).toBe(4);
    expect(callback.calls.allArgs()).toBe([message(21).data, message(21).data, message(22).data, message(23).data]);
  });
});
```

My code looks like this:

```
angular.module('core', []).constant('webSocket', WebSocket);

angular.module('core').factory('dataService', function ($interval, webSocket) {

  function openSocket() {
    sock = new webSocket('ws://localhost:9988');

    sock.onmessage = function (message) {
      var json = JSON.parse(message.data);

      onMessageSubscribers[json.type].forEach(function (sub) {
        sub(json);
      });
    };
  }

  function onMessage(type, func) {
    onMessageSubscribers[type].push(func);
  }

  openSocket();

  return {
    onMessage: onMessage
  };
});
```

`onMessageSubscribers` is a defined array with the correct types in it (int keys), but it's not relevant to the problem.

I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.onmessage(message)')

`onmessage` appears to be defined by the angular code that runs before the test, but I'm wondering if this is something to do with how a constructed object differs from a regular object in JS, I don't really have any experience with them.

I've tried a few different ways to do this, like calling `ws.prototype.onmessage` or just `ws.onmessage`.

If I place a `console.log(sock.onmessage);` in `dataService` at the appropriate place, and another log before I invoke `onmessage` in the tests:

> function (message) { ... }
>
> undefined

**How can I force an invoke of onmessage or any other WebSocket event?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `var sock = new webSocket();` new instance is being created from the `webSocket` constructor. Because of your design, this `sock` variable (`webSocket` instance) is not publicly exposed, therefore is not available in a test suite. Then, you define a property `onmessage` on this `sock` instance: `sock.onmessage = function () { ... }`.

What you want to do is to manually trigger `onmessage` from the test suite, but `onmessage` is attached to `sock` instance, and because you don't actually have access to `sock` instance from a test suite, therefore you don't have access to `onmessage` either.

You can't even access it from the prototype chain, because you don't have actual `sock` instance at hand.

What I've came up with is really tricky.

JavaScript has a *feature* - you can explicitly return object from a constructor ([info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)) and it will be assigned to a variable instead of a new instance object. For example:

```
function SomeClass() { return { foo: 'bar' }; }
var a = new SomeClass();
a; // { foo : 'bar' }; }
```

Here is how we can use it to access `onmessage`:

```
var ws,
    injectedWs;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('core', function ($provide) {

        // it will be an explicitly returned object
        injectedWs = {};

        // and it is a constructor - replacer for native WebSocket
        ws = function () {
            // return the object explicitly
            // it will be set to a 'sock' variable
            return injectedWs;
        };

        $provide.constant('webSocket', ws);
});
```

As a result, when in `DataService` you do `sock.onmessage = function () {};`, you actually assign it to that explicilty returned `injectedWs`, and it will be available in our test suite, because of the JavaScript another *feature* - objects are passed by reference.

Finally, you now are able to call `onmessage` in a test whenever you need  using `injectedWs.onmessage(message)`.

I've moved all the code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UIQtLJTyI6sBmAwBpJS7.

Note: There were some issues with suite expectations and JSON parsings, probably because you were not able to reach this code yet, I've fixed them so the tests could run.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In your opinion is this the preferred way to go or should I look into something like wrapping WebSocket in another layer of abstraction to remove the constructor frustrations?

Comment: I think it would be better to wrap it, and not only for easier testing, but also for the case when you would like to use another socket implementation (maybe some vendor library). This way you'd have to change only the wrapper's code. Also, you should rethink how you would like to implement the wrapper, because if it's gonna be a constructor again, you'll get in the same trouble. It could be a singleton service with methods like `wsService.create('ws://...')`, `wsService.on('message', fn)`, `wsService.emit('message')`

Comment: I have no intention of creating anything with a constructor! Thanks for your help.